# Can't get sitepreview on any Social Media

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, preview

I've made a website xxxxxxxxx.org . Although I've added the OG tags & stuff like below;

```html
<title>Test Title | xxxxxxxxx.org</title>
<meta name="description" content="xxxxxxxxx.org">
<meta property="og:title" content="xxxxxxxxx" />
<meta property="og:url" content="xxxxxxxxx.org/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="xxxxxxxxx.org">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://xxxxxxxxx.org">
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="tr_TR" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="xxxxxxxxx.org" />
<meta property="twitter:url" content="xxxxxxxxx.org/" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="xxxxxxxxx">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="xxxxxxxxx.org">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://xxxxxxxxx.org/">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@xxxxxxxxx" />
```

I still struggle to get previews on any social media except *LinkedIn*. I checked the "*[https://metatags.io/*"](https://metatags.io/*%22) and the "*[https://www.opengraph.xyz/*"](https://www.opengraph.xyz/*%22). There was no problem there, all platforms were working as its supposed to. I need a hand here thanks anyways.

Comment: Google and Twitter both support Facebook `og:image` and `og:description`, so you can remove `twitter:description` and `twitter:image` (as well as the classic `description` meta): be sure to include the Open Graph`prefix` in the HTML tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `og:image` tag on http://fabricatoday.org/ differ from your snippet. For example you current live version has:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="nymph/dynamic/img/settings/5f52740c80b02.png">
```

This should be a complete URL including a domain, just as you showed in your preview:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fabricatoday.org/nymph/dynamic/img/settings/5f52740c80b02.png">
```

Facebook offers a tool to check your opengraph info: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffabricatoday.org%2F

Twitter offers a similar tool to preview their cards: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Your `twitter:card` tag should be defined as followed:

> The card type, which will be one of “summary”, “summary_large_image”, “app”, or “player”.

[Source](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started#started)

For example:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
```